# Unity model size and position like in 3ds max?

Tags: model, unity-game-engine, 3dsmax

Is there a fast and easy way to get the same size of models in unity like in 3ds max?
I created a scene in 3ds max and exported the models to fbx. Then import them in unity, but the size and the positions are different. So I have to adjust them all by hand.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Just set up a rotation of 90 degrees on the x axis and export your FBX with Y up. Apart from that, make sure your units match. You should have no problems other than that.

Comment: I didn't found the option for rotating the x axis, but I did that in unity afterwards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, first in 3dsmax ensure the **centre of the object** you are importing into unity is in **the exact centre of the 3D Max project**, easiest way to do this is to select the object then right click the arrows next to X,Y and Z at the bottom of the user interface. (this sets them to 0 which will fix the position).

If you have a scene with multiple objects and you are exporting the entire scene together, do this for one object then place all other objects in there relevant position to the centre object.

You may also want to set the rotation, this can't be done simply by rotating an object in 3dsmax, all that does is change your perspective, you need to alter the pivot point. Let's say you imported an arrow, you want to arrows X to be its forward position (the direction the arrow faces), but in unity the arrow points along the Y axis, you need to alter the pivot. This video illustrates how to alter a pivot point clearly [3D Studio Max Change Pivot Position](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXCVQLLe4ks). (Trust me you will need to do this when things get complicated).

As for size you need to look up what units unity accepts from 3dsmax, 3dsmax has many units of scale that can be used for a project. Just have a search online for unity and 3dmax scale compatibility, I've never used unity so I couldn't tell you but I know using UDK that the scale in 3dsmax needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The type of units in MAX doesn't matter, e.g if your MAX scene is in inches then 1 inch = 1 unit in unity, if your MAX scene is in cm then 1cm = 1 unit in unity.

If the models you are exporting are all in the same MAX scene, and they are the correct size in relation to one another in that scene, then they will import into Unity as the correct size in relation to one another.

As for the position, an easy way to keep everything in the same place is to set the pivot point of all the objects to the same coordinates in the MAX scene eg(0,0) that way all the objects will be offset from a single position and you should be able to place them exactly as they are in the max scene very easily. Alternatively attach all the objects together in the MAX scene and export as a single object.